# Selecting clients who have an association with one column value, but not another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, where-clause, having

I am trying to make a report that list active clients (case_status = 'A') who have the old version of a document attached to them without the newer, but the way our database is laid out all documents are listed in one table, so some clients will have a dozen different documents attached to them. Some of them being duplicate documents.

Ex.

```
patient_id     Doc_code
p01            doc1
p01            doc2
p01            doc3
po1            doc4
p02            doc2
po2            doc3
```

I need to know who has a doc_code of 'DIAGDOC' and doesn't have a doc_code of 'DIAGDOC5', so we know who needs to be updated.

```
select 

de.patient_id,
de.episode_id

from doc_entity de
join patient p
on p.patient_id = de.patient_id and p.episode_id = de.episode_id
where p.case_status = 'A' 

group by de.patient_id, de.episode_id, de.doc_code
having (de.doc_code in ('DIAGDOC'))and (de.doc_code not in ('DIAGDOC5'))
order by de.patient_id, de.episode_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would an except clause work?

```
select
de.patient_id,
de.episode_id

from doc_entity de
join patient p
on p.patient_id = de.patient_id and p.episode_id = de.episode_id
where p.case_status = 'A' 
and de.doc_code = 'DIAGDOC'

EXCEPT

select 

de.patient_id,
de.episode_id

from doc_entity de
join patient p
on p.patient_id = de.patient_id and p.episode_id = de.episode_id
where p.case_status = 'A' 
and de.doc_code = 'DIAGDOC5'*
```

the top block returns all rows with diagdoc and the except block removes all those with diagdoc5 leaving only those with an out of date document

Comment: I seem to have some clients slipping through the cracks. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: are there people  ith documents like diagdoc2 but not diagdoc that are getting through? replacing the = diagdoc in the top block with like 'diagdoc%' would then filter the results to anybody that has a version of the file but not the latest so somebody with docs 2,3,4,5 would not come though but somebody with 2,3,4 would however they would not have been cuaght with my original query

Comment: Actually I think that worked. I hadn't used the Except clause before, but I think it'll be my new best friend. We had a clinical person update two documents that happened to be at the top of my list I made earlier this morning. I'll do a little more spot checking then send you a check mark.

Comment: it is handy, also worth looking up intersect and union they work in the same manner intersect returns results from both queries and union returns from either https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191523(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I will thank you. This is much simpler then the correlated subquery I thought I was going to have to make. I don't usually code, so those are a little tricky for me when I come up to situations that may need them.

Answer (score 1):

Does the below work -

```
select 
    aa.patient_id, aa.episode_id 
from 
(
    select  
            de.patient_id
        ,   de.episode_id
        ,   MAX(case doc_code WHEN 'DIAGDOC'  THEN 'YES'  ELSE 'NO' end) as 'DIAGDOCExists'
        ,   MAX(case doc_code WHEN 'DIAGDOC5' THEN 'YES'  ELSE 'NO' end) as 'DIAGDOC5Exists'
    from 
        doc_entity de join patient p on p.patient_id = de.patient_id and p.episode_id = de.episode_id
    where 
        p.case_status = 'A' 
    group by 
        de.patient_id, de.episode_id
) as aa where aa.DIAGDOCExists = 'YES' and aa.DIAGDOC5Exists = 'NO'
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error from the when which I think is, becuase there should only be 1 on line 8 and 9, but when I remove the duplicate when's I get syntax error on the ) on line 8.

Comment: try now. not sure how double when got introduced, also end clause was missing.